# twitter oauth with golang

Tags: go, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to make this request "oauth/request_token" using this code in Go:

```
// GET PARAMS TO REQUEST
t := time.Now().UTC()
values := make(url.Values)
values.Add("oauth_nonce", auth.ANonce)
values.Add("oauth_callback", auth.Path) //http://localhost:8080/oauth
values.Add("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1")
values.Add("oauth_timestamp", t.String())
values.Add("oauth_consumer_key", auth.ClientID)

// GET SIGNATURE
baseString := fmt.Sprintf("POST&%s&%s", auth.Path, values.Encode())
key := fmt.Sprintf("%s&", auth.SecretID)

// GENERATE HASH
mac := hmac.New(sha1.New, []byte(key))
mac.Write([]byte(baseString))
signature := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(mac.Sum(nil))

// MAKE THE REQUEST
values.Add("oauth_version", "1.0")
values.Add("oauth_signature", signature)
client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", auth.RequestToken, nil)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("getOAuthToken Request Error: %v", err)
}
// SET HEADER
req.Header.Set("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("OAuth oauth_nonce=\"%s\", oauth_callback=\"%s\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"%s\", oauth_consumer_key=\"%s\", oauth_signature=\"%s\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"", auth.ANonce, auth.Path, t.String(), auth.ClientID, signature))
res, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("getOAuthToken Client Error: %v", err)
}
defer res.Body.Close()

bs, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("getOAuthToken Error: %v", err)
}

log.Printf("getOAuthToken Response: %s\n", string(bs))
```

Problem is that I always receive this error as a response: "getOAuthToken Response:

> {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}

I believe that the main problem is with my signature, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: One issue is that OAuth 1 uses standard base 64 encoding, not URL encoding as written in the question.  I suggest using a package like https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/oauth1/oauth or https://godoc.org/github.com/mrjones/oauth.  If you want to implement your own signature method, then run your code against the test cases in those packages.

Comment: I tried to use standard and didn't work.

Comment: There are many details to get exactly right. I am not surprised that there's another thing to fix.  I doubt you will get someone to debug the code here.  Use an existing package.

Answer (score 1):

Well the main problem really was with my **signature** although the code had other problems, even then I managed to solve the problem and if someone ever had the same problem I'll left my code solution on [github](https://github.com/sampalm/golangWebTraining/blob/master/00_hands-on/10_oauth/04_twitter/oauth.go).

Comment: thanks for your answer and questions, also you should not include your api key and secret in public files.